# dropping rows with null elements increases frequency in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this code to remove rows for those values whose frequency is very less. It removes rows with less frequency but it also increase frequency of remaining rows.

```
df = xl.parse("Tabelle1")
#removing places for which frequency is very less 
freq = df['bestSpot'].value_counts()
print(freq[:12])
to_remove = freq[freq<7].index
df['bestSpot'].replace(to_remove,None,inplace = True)
df = df.dropna()
freq = df['bestSpot'].value_counts()  
print(freq[:12])
```

Output:

```
Weissenstein    28
Fiesch          17
Fanas           15
Niesen          11
Brunni           8
Amisbühl         6
Balderen         4
Marbachegg       4
Cimetta          3
Lai Alv          3
Schwängimatt     2
Mornera          2
Name: bestSpot, dtype: int64
Weissenstein    33
Fiesch          28
Fanas           19
Niesen          13
Brunni          10
Name: bestSpot, dtype: int64
```

Isn't it unwanted behaviour? Does anyone know reason for this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DYZ why does it happen? I mean why is frequency increased?  Isn't it unwanted behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you pass `None` as the new value. Try using `np.nan` instead:

```
...
to_remove = freq[freq<7].index
df['bestSpot'].replace(to_remove,np.nan ,inplace = True)
df = df.dropna()
...
```

Comment: Thanks :) it works. Can you explain why does frequency increases when using None?

Comment: the `replace` method has a special treatment for value `None`. It does not replace the values with `None` as you expect it would. If my answer was helpful please accept it.